# Why is this pipeline behave differently in ksh93 compared to bash?

Tags: bash, ksh

I had an issue with a ksh93 code. As it was very complex I started reducing it to an example code that will reproduce the same issue. I ended up with this:

```
set -o pipefail;

{
        echo "progress" 1>&3 | false
} 3>&1 | cat | \
        while read pv_output; do
                echo "meanwhile ... we got "
                echo $pv_output | cat
        done

echo $?
```

When I run this code with ksh93 it outputs "0", when I run it with bash it outputs "1".

```
# echo "ksh93";ksh93 ./x1.sh ;echo "bash"; bash ./x1.sh
ksh93
meanwhile ... we got
progress
0
bash
meanwhile ... we got
progress
1
```

However if I start fiddling with the code, and remove the first `cat`, both shells return "1"

```
set -o pipefail;

{
        echo "progress" 1>&3 | false
} 3>&1 | \
        while read pv_output; do
                echo "meanwhile ... we got "
                echo $pv_output | cat
        done

echo $?
```

Or... if I leave in the first `cat`, but I remove the second one from inside the `while`, they work the same way again.

```
set -o pipefail;

{
        echo "progress" 1>&3 | false
} 3>&1 | cat | \
        while read pv_output; do
                echo "meanwhile ... we got "
                echo $pv_output
        done

echo $?
```

Now, for this example I used `cat` for simplicity's sake. In real life the first `cat` is actually an `awk` processing the output of a complicated command. The second `cat` is actually a `sed`. I mention these, so that it is clear that the `cat` command in itself is not the culprit.

Comment: Running the first script in ksh93 gives 1 on my machine (same for bash).

Comment: @Robin479 What version of ksh93 do you have? Mine sais `version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-03-05`

Comment: $ ksh93 --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01

Comment: As explained in detail http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 'In most shells, each command of a pipeline is executed in a separate SubShell'. I won't expect different shells to handle returncodes from a command somewhere in the sequence of pipes in the same way. Same for changing the number or sequence in the pipe.

Comment: @ULick Thank you for your comment. However according to Bash and Ksh documentations, both should return the same output. It seems like a bug in the Ksh I have.

Comment: I tried variations of your code. If the last part of the pipe (the while loop) is not placed explicitly in a subshell `( while ... done )` then it seems not all commands within the while loop are considered to be part of the pipe and are thus able to override the value in `$?`. So you don't get the pipe's return code, but whatever the shell decided to take as the last command. If placed in a subshell it is always returning the result from the pipe.